# Multiple instances of jQuery plugin on same page is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have searched on this site but did not get what I need.
My issue is that I have created a jquery plugin for carousels, its working fine on 1 instance, but if I created multiple instance its only working on last.

ex: 
    $('#one').smartCarousel(); // its not working 
    $('#two').smartCarousel(); // its working

Here is the plugin code:

```
;(function($){

// default options
var defaults = {
    slide : 1,
    autoPlay : false,
    autoPlayTime : 3000,
    speed : 400,
    next : false,
    prev : false,
    reverse : false,
    show : 4
}

// function
function sc(el, o){
    this.config = $.extend({}, defaults, o);
    this.el = el;
    this.init();
    return this;
}

// set init configurations
sc.prototype.init = function(){

    $this = this;
    // get children
    $this.children = $this.el.children();

    // wrape element, add basic css properties
    $this.el.wrap('<div class="smartCarouselWrapper clearfix"></div>')
        .css({
            position: 'absolute',
        }).parent().css({
            height: $this.el.outerHeight(true), // Height is setting on line 57
            width: '100%',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            position: 'relative'
        });

    // Show element by config
    // Calculate width by deviding wraper width
    // Set width of items
    $elw = $this.el.parent().width()/$this.config.show;
    $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).width($elw);
    });

    w = $elw*$this.config.slide; // init width

    // get width, hadle diffrent width
    $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
        w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    // set lement width
    $this.el.width(w);

    // Set height for wrapper 
    $this.el.parent().height($this.el.outerHeight(true));

    // check if next handle assigned
    if ($this.config.next != false ) {
        $(this.config.next).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $this.next();
        });
    };

    // check if prev handle assigned
    if ($this.config.prev != false ) {
        $(this.config.prev).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $this.prev();
        });
    };

    $this.ready();
} // end of inti

sc.prototype.autoPlay = function(){
    // if reverse enabled
    if (this.config.reverse != false) { this.prev(); } else { this.next(); };
}

// do stuffs when ready
sc.prototype.ready = function(){
    if(this.config.autoPlay != false){
        this.timeOut = setTimeout('$this.autoPlay()', this.config.autoPlayTime);
    }
}

sc.prototype.next = function(){
    $this = this;

    clearTimeout($this.timeOut);


    l = 0; // left
    i = 0; // index

    // Add width to l from each element, limiting through slide
    $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
        if (i < $this.config.slide) {
            l -= $(this).outerWidth(true);
            //Clone first item after last for smooth animation
            $this.el.append($this.children.eq(i).clone());
            $this.children = $this.el.children();
        };
        i++;
    });

    // animat to show next items and appent prev items to end
    $this.el.stop().animate({
        left: l},
        $this.config.speed, function() {

            i = 0; // index
            $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
                if (i < $this.config.slide) {
                    $this.children.last().remove();
                    $this.children = $this.el.children();
                };
                i++;
            });

            i = 0;
            $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
                if (i < $this.config.slide) {
                    $(this).appendTo($this.el);
                    $this.el.css('left', parseInt($this.el.css('left'))+$(this).outerWidth(true));
                };
                i++;
            });
            $this.children = $this.el.children();
            $this.ready();
    });
} // end of next

sc.prototype.prev = function(){

    $this = this;

    clearTimeout($this.timeOut);

    l = 0; // left
    i = 0; // index

    //move last item to first through slide
    $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
        if (i < $this.config.slide) {

            //Clone first item after last for smooth animation
            $this.el.prepend($this.children.eq(($this.children.length-1)-i).clone());
            l -= $this.children.eq(($this.children.length-1)-i).outerWidth(true);
            $this.el.css('left', l);
            console.log(1);
        };
        i++;

    });
    console.log(l);
    $this.children = $this.el.children();
    // animate back to 0
    $this.el.stop().animate({left: 0}, $this.config.speed, function(){ 

        i = 0;
        $this.children.each(function(index, el) {
            if (i <= $this.config.slide) {
                $this.children.eq($this.children.length-i).remove();
            };
            i++;
        });

        $this.children = $this.el.children();
        $this.ready(); 
    });
} // end of prev

// plugin
if (typeof $.smartCarousel != 'function') {  
    $.fn.smartCarousel = function(o){
        if (this.length > 0) {
            new sc(this.first(), o);
        };
        return this;
    }
}else{
    console.log('Function already declared.');
    return this;
}

}(jQuery))
```

Here the html:

`<ul class="smart-carousel-list clearfix" id="one">
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Premium Quality  DATES</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Variety of Export Quality  RICE</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Sports Goods</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Surgical Items</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Bad Sheets</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Towals</h3>
    </li>
    <li><!-- Image here -->
      <h3>Fruits & Vegetable</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>`

HERE IS THE CSS:

`

```
.smart-carousel{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.smart-carousel-list{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.smart-carousel-list li {
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box !important;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.smart-carousel-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
}
.smart-carousel:hover .smart-carousel-nav{
    opacity: 1;
}
.smart-carousel-nav a{
    display: block;
    width: 29px;
    height: 28px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    outline: none;
}
.smart-carousel-nav a.sc_next{
    background-image: url('next.png');
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
.smart-carousel-nav a.sc_prev{
    background-image: url('prev.png');
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}


/**
 * STYLE FOR TYPE : Images;
 */

.smart-carousel.type-images .smart-carousel-list li img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/**
 * STYLE FOR TYPE : Products;
 */
.smart-carousel.type-products .smart-carousel-list li{
    border: solid 1px #efefef;
}
.smart-carousel.type-products .smart-carousel-list li img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.smart-carousel.type-products .smart-carousel-list li h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.smart-carousel.type-products .smart-carousel-list li h3 a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.smart-carousel.type-products .smart-carousel-list li h3 a span{
    float: right;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/**
 * STYLE FOR TYPE : Posts;
 */
.smart-carousel.type-posts .smart-carousel-list li{
    /*border: solid 1px #efefef;*/
}
.smart-carousel.type-posts .smart-carousel-list li img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.smart-carousel.type-posts .smart-carousel-list li h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.smart-carousel.type-posts .smart-carousel-list li h3 a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.smart-carousel.type-posts .smart-carousel-list li h3 a span{
    float: right;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

`

Comment: Not enough code. How are you initiating #one and #two?

Comment: You plugin does not appear to be following any standard pattern *for jQuery plugins*. What did you base it on? e.g. they normally store class instance `data` on the element, so that the correct instances maps to the correct DOM element.

Comment: Do you have any styling to go with it? I have built a JSFiddle for the example, but it will do nothing without the CSS :)

Comment: Yes, Please see new edit. I posted CSS too

Comment: This site does not allowed me to add images in html. I just commeted images line

Comment: Start with this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b7u4635x/ and see if you get it functioning there. I am not 100% sure what it is meant to be doing.

Comment: please check updated JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/b7u4635x/1/

Comment: I have added auto play on

Comment: Better, now I have something to fix :)

Comment: The entire problem is right here: `$this = this;`

Comment: @KevinB: Yes, but not the only problem. please add any fixes to JSFiddle and try them. Cheers

Comment: Did not get it :( can you explain ?

Comment: It may not be the only problem, but it is the problem that causes it to not work on multiple elements at the same time (which seems to be the focus of this question.)

Comment: Okay, all appears to be working now... Please check revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a global variable in your plugin, thus making it impossible for the plugin to work with more than one element because each call to the plugin will overwrite the `$this` for the previous instance to target the new element.

you simply need to add `var` in each location where it is missing.

```
var $this = this;
```

This will of course break any other place where you attempted to use a global `$this` (such as the `setTimeout('$this.autoplay()',200)`, so you will need to re-write that portion of the code to not execute autoplay() in that way.

Comment: Please try this in the JSFiddle... I think there are more issues.

Comment: That's a different problem entirely, caused by the way you are using `$this` within a string in a setTimeout.

Comment: Its also breaking it. after adding var its not working. can you try it in JSFiddle ?

Comment: it breaks it because the mentioned setTimeout is using `$this` in a string, which would require `$this` to be global to work, which is not going to work for your plugin. you will need to rewrite that part of the plugin.

Comment: I tries as this this.timeOut = setTimeout(function(){$this.autoPlay()}, this.config.autoPlayTime); but not workingstill

Comment: this.timeOut = setTimeout(function(){this.autoPlay()}, this.config.autoPlayTime); is not working either

Comment: Right, because `this` is window (because `setTimeout` is a property of `window`). see my fiddle 2 comments up.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin is written to only connect to a single jQuery element at a time. You can improve that like this:

```
// plugin
if (typeof $.smartCarousel != 'function') {
    $.fn.smartCarousel = function (o) {
        this.each(function(){
            // Connect to each jQuery element
            new sc($(this), o);
        });
        return this;
    }
} else {
    console.log('Function already declared.');
    return this;
}
```

As for the other problems, you have a single global `$this` shared all over the place. I added all the missing var $this where required for you and correctly reference it in the timer (via an anonymous function wrapper, so that I can reference the local `$this`):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b7u4635x/4/

```
;
(function ($) {

    // default options
    var defaults = {
        slide: 1,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlayTime: 1000,
        speed: 400,
        next: false,
        prev: false,
        reverse: false,
        show: 4
    }

    // function
        function sc(el, o) {
            this.config = $.extend({}, defaults, o);
            this.el = el;
            this.init();
            return this;
        }

        // set init configurations
        sc.prototype.init = function () {

            var $this = this;
            // get children
            $this.children = $this.el.children();

            // wrape element, add basic css properties
            $this.el.wrap('<div class="smartCarouselWrapper clearfix"></div>')
                .css({
                position: 'absolute',
            }).parent().css({
                height: $this.el.outerHeight(true), // Height is setting on line 57
                width: '100%',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                position: 'relative'
            });

            // Show element by config
            // Calculate width by deviding wraper width
            // Set width of items
            var $elw = $this.el.parent().width() / $this.config.show;
            $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
                $(this).width($elw);
            });

            var w = $elw * $this.config.slide; // init width

            // get width, hadle diffrent width
            $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
                w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
            });

            // set lement width
            $this.el.width(w);

            // Set height for wrapper 
            $this.el.parent().height($this.el.outerHeight(true));

            // check if next handle assigned
            if ($this.config.next != false) {
                $(this.config.next).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    $this.next();
                });
            };

            // check if prev handle assigned
            if ($this.config.prev != false) {
                $(this.config.prev).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    $this.prev();
                });
            };

            $this.ready();
        } // end of inti

        sc.prototype.autoPlay = function () {
            var $this = this;
            // if reverse enabled
            if ($this.config.reverse != false) {
                $this.prev();
            } else {
                $this.next();
            };
        }

        // do stuffs when ready
        sc.prototype.ready = function () {
            var $this = this;
            if ($this.config.autoPlay != false) {
                $this.timeOut = setTimeout(function(){$this.autoPlay();}, $this.config.autoPlayTime);
            }
        }

    sc.prototype.next = function () {
        var $this = this;

        clearTimeout($this.timeOut);


        var l = 0; // left
        var i = 0; // index

        // Add width to l from each element, limiting through slide
        $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
            if (i < $this.config.slide) {
                l -= $(this).outerWidth(true);
                //Clone first item after last for smooth animation
                $this.el.append($this.children.eq(i).clone());
                $this.children = $this.el.children();
            };
            i++;
        });

        // animat to show next items and appent prev items to end
        $this.el.stop().animate({
            left: l
        },
        $this.config.speed, function () {

            i = 0; // index
            $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
                if (i < $this.config.slide) {
                    $this.children.last().remove();
                    $this.children = $this.el.children();
                };
                i++;
            });

            i = 0;
            $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
                if (i < $this.config.slide) {
                    $(this).appendTo($this.el);
                    $this.el.css('left', parseInt($this.el.css('left')) + $(this).outerWidth(true));
                };
                i++;
            });
            $this.children = $this.el.children();
            $this.ready();
        });
    } // end of next

    sc.prototype.prev = function () {

        var $this = this;

        clearTimeout($this.timeOut);

        var l = 0; // left
        var i = 0; // index

        //move last item to first through slide
        $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
            if (i < $this.config.slide) {

                //Clone first item after last for smooth animation
                $this.el.prepend($this.children.eq(($this.children.length - 1) - i).clone());
                l -= $this.children.eq(($this.children.length - 1) - i).outerWidth(true);
                $this.el.css('left', l);
                console.log(1);
            };
            i++;

        });
        console.log(l);
        $this.children = $this.el.children();
        // animate back to 0
        $this.el.stop().animate({
            left: 0
        }, $this.config.speed, function () {

            i = 0;
            $this.children.each(function (index, el) {
                if (i <= $this.config.slide) {
                    $this.children.eq($this.children.length - i).remove();
                };
                i++;
            });

            $this.children = $this.el.children();
            $this.ready();
        });
    } // end of prev

    // plugin
    if (typeof $.smartCarousel != 'function') {
        $.fn.smartCarousel = function (o) {
            this.each(function () {
                new sc($(this), o);
            });
            return this;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Function already declared.');
        return this;
    }

}(jQuery));

//$('.smart-carousel-list').smartCarousel();

$('#one').smartCarousel();
$('#two').smartCarousel();
```

Comment: Thank you, But I created it as it is. because if some add this plugin on array of object than it will work on first element only.

Comment: $('#one, #two') will not allowed. only $('#one') and $('#tow')

Comment: I did used your code to just check, but the problem is same :(

Comment: it not mush this worse :P well I just implemented @kevin's suggestion that solve the problem. and you fixed it the same way. sorry can not give you reward. I dont much point to thumb up